# how to remove space between characters of a string using wide char to multibytes?

Tags: c, file, visual-c++

I have a file open in winhex look like follow.

1F 00 48 3A 18 00 00 00 53 00 70 00 6F 00 75 00
73 00 65 00 5F 00 61 00 7A 00 61 00 6D 00 00 00

I am reading the above hex data from file and write it to a text file . My code is as follow.

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<iostream.h>
int main()
{
FILE *pFile, *tempFile;
char *Main_buffer;
int nOfRecord, TotalSize, data=0;
pFile = fopen("C:\\wab files\\Main.wab", "rb"); 
if(pFile == NULL)
{
    fputs("file error", stderr);
    exit(1);
}
tempFile = fopen("C:\\myfile.text","wb");
if(tempFile == NULL)
{
    fputs("file not open", stderr);
    exit(2);
}
 fread(&nOfRecord, 1, 4, pFile);
 fread(&TotalSize, 1, 4, pFile);
 data = TotalSize;
 char* Main_buffer = (char*)malloc(data*sizeof(data));
 fread(Main_buffer, 1, TotalSize, pFile);
 fwrite(Main_buffer, 1, TotalSize, tempFile);
 free(Main_buffer);
 return 0;
}
```

This code gives a text file in which data is written as follow.

p a l @ g m a i l . c o

In above data there is a space between each character . How to remove space from the data, and write in a text file . Please explain by writing  some code as an example for wide char to multi bytes . Thanks you in advance .

Comment: It's probably written as a UTF-16 string (i.e. wide chars). You could read it in as wide chars and then either process it as wide or convert to some other format either manually or with e.g. WideCharToMultiByte

Comment: The hex values represent a UNICODE string. If you want that in a text file, you can narrow it to an ansi string if possible or you could open it as unicode file. I think most editors will use unicode automatically if you have a specific byte header first thing in the file.

Comment: @Rup: how can i covert it from WideCharToMultiByte please tell me by writting code.

Comment: can you give the binary data

Comment: @kunal: my data is in hex looking like below . Please help me if you have any solution . 1F 00 45 3A 12 00 00 00 68 00 69 00 69 00 69 00 2E 00 2E 00 2E 00 2E 00 00 00 1F 00 4F 3A 0A 00 00 00 61 00 7A 00 7A 00 75 00 00 00 1F 00 44 3A 0A 00 00 00 61 00 7A 00 61 00 6D 00 00 00 1F 00 11 3A 0C 00 00 00 6D 00 61 00 6C 00 69 00 6B 00 00 00 1F 00 06 3A 0A 00 00 00 6D 00 6F 00 68 00 64 00 00 00

Answer (score 1):

There are basically 2 ways of doing it:

1. Manually removing spaces from the generated ASCII thing.
2. Use a library to do the work for you (of course if you are allowed to). My preference goes toward
   http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iconv

which (as said on the Wikipedia page) has a free implementation in GCC so you can try to play with it.
And here the link to the Linux lib:
http://www.gnu.org/software/libiconv/#TOCintroduction

**UPDATE**

Here is an example in C of how to use libiconv:
http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/iconv-Examples.html

Answer (score 0):

Try using strtok() from < string.h > .