# How do I parse a WAB file?

Tags: c, visual-c++

I have a WAB file (Windows Address Book), such as the following (in hex):

```
1F00483A 18000000 53007000 6F007500 73006500 5F006100 7A006100 6D000000 
1F10583A 02000000‌ 32000000 16000000 4E006500 77002000 43006800 69006C00 
64003200 00001400 00004E00 65007700 2‌0004300 68006900 6C006400 00001F00 
183A0C00 00005200 20002600 20004400 00001F00 193A2800 00‌006D00 61006900
6E002000 62007200 61006E00 63006800 20006700 75007200 67006100 6F006E00
000‌​0
```

I am trying to read the binary data from the file and output it as text.  My current code is as follows:

```
int nOfRecord, TotalSize, data=0;
fread(&nOfRecord, 1, 4, pFile);
fread(&TotalSize, 1, 4, pFile);
data = TotalSize;
char* Main_buffer = (char*)malloc(data*sizeof(data));
fread(Main_buffer, 1, TotalSize, pFile);
fwrite(Main_buffer, 1, TotalSize, tempFile);
free(Main_buffer);
```

when i am open output text file . The data is found as follows:
S p o u s e _ a z a m
there is a space between each character . How can i remove this space.

Comment: There are lots of ways to convert `char` to `unsigned short`.  Are you converting UTF-8 text to UTF-16?  Are you converting a plain array to an array?  **What is the desired output?**

Comment: @ Dietrich Epp: the output is look like     a b h i s h e k p .       there is a space between each character . I wants to remove this space

Comment: Where did "abhishekp" come from?  The format looks like it contains both binary and textual data, but the text it contains is "Spouse_azam".  Without knowledge of the format it is difficult to know how you would want to decode it.

Comment: @Dietrich Epp: Yes, it is right the text it contains is "Spouse_azam" but when, i am writing this text to a text file using function fwrite(Main_buffer, 1, TotalSize, tempFile);                        there is a space between each character of string . How can i remove this space.

Comment: My point is that there is more than just a space, there is other binary data there too.  Without knowing what format the binary data is in, how can we remove it?

Comment: @Dietrich Epp: The format of binary data is UTF-8 .

Comment: UTF-8 is a text format.  I'm talking about parts of the input like `1F 00 48 3A`, which is almost certainly not UTF-8.

Comment: Repeat of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19705070/how-to-remove-space-between-characters-of-a-string-using-wide-char-to-multibytes

Comment: @ Dietrich Epp: I have give you below my all binary data.  1F00483A18000000530070006F007500730065005F0061007A0061006D0000001F10583A0200000032000000160000004E006500770020004300680069006C00640032000000140000004E006500770020004300680069006C00640000001F00183A0C0000005200200026002000440000001F00193A280000006D00610069006E0020006200720061006E00630068002000670075007200670061006F006E000000       This my data each time  i am doing same thing

Comment: [see here](http://www.blogosfera.co.uk/2013/10/how-to-remove-space-between-characters-of-a-string/)

Comment: I can see that the binary format contains what appears to be NUL-terminated UTF-16 strings preceded by a 16-bit length, where the length includes the NUL byte.  Beyond that, I'm not sure what format this data is in.  Is it a dump from some database, like PostgreSQL or something?

Comment: @Dietrich Epp: This is a windows address book in ms outlook express after opening in winhex . The format of data is .wab   .

Comment: I don't know anything about the WAB file format.

Comment: Are you aware of the existence of the [Windows Address Book API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms629440.aspx)? There's also an open source [libwab](http://www.filewut.com/spages/page.php/software/libwab) library. Before you ask, I haven't personally used either.